# Dynamic width of div

Tags: css

I would like my div to have the maximum width available, so that the text inside it will wrap if needed when the page is shrunk (just the text should wrap when div will have his max width instead breaking all structure). I found a solution on the internet, but I can't translate it to my specific case. I have looked everywhere and cannot find a way to solve this problem...

All I know that I have to use `display: flex` and `flex: 1 1 auto;` somehow, but I can't find good way to do that.

@@@@@EDIT

The problem was that I was using strings without spaces, what was breaking the structure. Adding `word-break: break-all;` fixed that. Below I put my code. Maybe will be useful for someone

HTML:

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="div1">
  
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div21"></div>
    <div class="div21auto">          fadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfssfadsfsfadsfssfadsfsfadsfssfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfsfadsfssfadsfsfadsfssfadsfsfadsfssfadsfsfadsfs
    </div>
    <div class="div21"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="div1">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    /* important stuff for this example */


.row {
  display:flex;
}
.div2 {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.div1 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 90px
}
.div21 {
  height: 30px
    
}
.div21auto {
  height: 30px
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  word-break: break-all;
}

/* other stuff */
div {
  padding:1em;
  margin:0.2em;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.125)
}
.row {
  width:80%;
  padding:1em;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? It appears to wrap correctly as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yes, just find out. It works. My problem was that I was using the long string wihtout spaces, so this was breaking the structure. Adding also `word-break: break-all;` fixed that issue

Comment: Before you ask the next time, please go rerad [ask] and [mre]. The minimal code necessary to reproduce your problem, belongs _directly_ into your question, in text form and properly formatted (or as a stack snippet, when applicable) - please do not just dump it onto external platforms.

Comment: I'll remember that. I have fixed a question a little ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe set a min-width attribute for that div? That way, that element will always be *at least* a certain width.